# lucene query replace substring using grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

I have **Grafana** v5.0.4 and DataBase **ELASTICSEARCH** 5.х

In Base have field with ***keyword***:

1. message.keyword: "<30>May 15 09:50:32 workers foo : 2018/05/15 09:50:32 foo Micropay Transaction Complite: 15135135151313313"
2. message.keyword: "<30>May 15 19:50:32 workers goo: 2018/05/15 19:50:32 foo Micropay Transaction Complite: 447416847463185468"
3. message.keyword: "<30>May 17 03:50:32 workers foo: 2018/05/15 19:50:32 foo Micropay Transaction Complite: 447416847463185468"

I make query from grafana: message.keyword:(*workers foo*) with metric: **count** and group by **Terms** @timestamp and Then by **Terms** message.keyword as table

1. "<30>May 15 09:50:32 workers foo : 2018/05/15 09:50:32 foo Micropay Transaction Complite: 15135135151313313"
2. "<30>May 17 03:50:32 workers foo: 2018/05/15 19:50:32 foo Micropay Transaction Complite: 447416847463185468"

***Question***:  How can i make query to make this data without first substring("<30>May 15 09:50:32 workers foo : )

***Expectation***:

1. "2018/05/15 09:50:32 foo Micropay Transaction Complite: 15135135151313313"
2. "2018/05/15 19:50:32 foo Micropay Transaction Complite: 447416847463185468"

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: nothing, I can't understand how to make my query....(